# "[VERBOSE-2:dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel., null, null)"

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, flutter-dependencies, findbugs

After installing firebase, this problem started to appear, it works on android but it's no working on ios.
[image]

I tried everything but it didn't work, what do you advise me to do?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information, please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557)